# Where to place business logic in Angular2

Tags: angular

Is it good practice to put all my business logic in an angular 2 application in a service in the root component?  Otherwise, where should the main entrypoint for the business logic be?

thanks

Comment: what do you mean  by `bussiness logic` here ?

Answer (score 1):

in my opinion business logic is close to data - so should be with services